# Чтение текста из PDF со страницы сайты

Tags: c#

Использую библиотеку xNet для POST / GET запросов

И посредством POST запроса, получаю ссылку на страницу с PDF файлом.

`Content-Type: application/pdf`

Какой самый простой способ чтения этого PDF ? Изъятие из него текста.

Спасибо!

Comment: Почему вы вдруг решили перейти на xNet оО Ведь двигались в правильном направление, спрашивали про правильные классы и вдруг xNet... Советую завязывать с ней, ибо она уже очень давно заброшена автором, а из за нынешний тенденции отказа от tls 1.0, она становится еще более не актуальной, ибо написана на .NET 4, а он не поддерживает без костылей новые версии tls. По поводу вопроса - используете библиотеку, которая работает с PDF, скачиваете/считываете файл и разбираете библиотекой. Просто так получить от туда текст вряд ли получится.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да), действительно я чуть съехал, когда встретился с какой то проблемой, так как проще было cделать какое то решение быстро на xNet, так как немного с ним был знаком, а другое только познавал. Но обещаю вернуться на правильную дорожку xD

Comment: @EvgeniyZ "Просто так получить от туда текст вряд ли получится."  Имеете ввиду что надо будет OCR использовать ?

Comment: Ну как вы открываете PDF с интернета? Вы его скачиваете на компьютер, а там уже отдаете Acrobat (или как там его) для разбора, ну либо у вас в браузере стоит плагин, который также берет эти данные и разбирает. Также и программно у вас два пути: 1. Скачать файл и открыть его чем надо (в интернете полно dll для работы с PDF форматом), либо получить байты данного файла и без скачивания работать напрямую (хотя это по сути тоже скачивание), отдав эти байты в виде Stream нужной dll (думаю они это умеют).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял вас, буду разбираться.